# Create an instance of a composable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I created a little composable, which is supposed to help me handling modals and slide overs.

This is the composable **:**

```js
export function useSlideover() {

    const isOpen = ref(false);

    function toggle(){
        isOpen.value = !isOpen.value;
    }

    function open(){
        isOpen.value = true;
    }

    function close(){
        isOpen.value = false;
    }

    return { isOpen,  toggle, open, close}
}

export function useModal() {

    const isOpen = ref(false);

    function toggle(){
        isOpen.value = !isOpen.value;
    }

    function open(){
        isOpen.value = true;
    }

    function close(){
        isOpen.value = false;
    }

    return { isOpen,  toggle, open, close}
}
```

If I use it in a component like this **:**

```
const {isOpen, open, close, toggle} = useSlideover();

...

open();
```

everything works nice. But from time to time, there are two components using this composable at the very same time - e.g. there is a modal that opens a smaller modal.

What happens here is that if I use the `close()` function on the smaller modal, the parent-modal closes too, as `isOpen` changes to `false` for this component, too.

My question is: How can I handle the state of each modal individually ?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The scenario you describe won't be reproducible with this code. At this point these composables will produce totally unrelated states. The rest depends on the actual implementation of a modal, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the useModal and pass the ref of the modal you want to show/hide

```
export function useModal() {

    function toggle(isOpen){
        isOpen.value = !isOpen.value;
    }

    function open(isOpen){
        isOpen.value = true;
    }

    function close(isOpen){
        isOpen.value = false;
    }

    return {toggle, open, close}
}
```

and in the setup use it like this

```
const mod = ref(false)
const innerMod = ref(false)

const {open, close, toggle} = useModal(); 

open(mod)
```